# Future method rollback

Tags: apex, future, rollback

I have a `System.LimitException` problem: Apex CPU time limit exceeded in Apex, and I have therefore modified a synchronous functionality in asynchronous functionality by changing the method in `@future`.

The method performs numerous inserts in different object, in the case of an error during the insertion phase (for example the last record) for all the others, does it have a rollback or remain in the system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your synchronous functionality and asynchronous `@future` method execute in different transactions. The rollback mechanism is effective within a single transaction, and is affected by your own exception handling or explicit savepoint/rollback code.

Let's say, for example, that you have the following setup:

```
public static void synchronousMethod() {
    Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test');
    insert a;

    futureMethod(a.Id);
}

@future
public static void futureMethod(Id actId) {
    Contact c1 = new Contact(LastName = 'Test', AccountId = actId);
    insert c1;

    Contact c2 = new Contact(AccountId = actId);
    insert c2;
}
```

That future method will throw an exception because the required field `LastName` is missing from `c2`. As a result, the insert of `c1` will be rolled back, because the exception is not caught.

However, the insert of `a` will *not* be rolled back, because it took place in a separate transaction. The Account "Test" will remain in the database, but won't have any Contacts.

You can implement your own exception handling to prevent (some) rollbacks. Limits exceptions and `System.UnexpectedException`s cannot be caught and handled, and will result in a rollback of the transaction. You shouldn't use an exception handler just to prevent a rollback - that can leave your database in an inconsistent state. Use exception handling when you can actually handle and recover from an exception that occurs.

Comment: David- in given example, account id is passed to future method...And assigned as account of new contacts. Now if acc is not inserted due to some reason ...Then would insertion of contacts not throw exception as well because we are providing account id which does not exist...?

Comment: @AyubAnsari It certainly would. However, if the Account insert threw an exception in `synchronousMethod()`, we'd never get to the invocation of the future method.

Comment: I have all the inserts in the future method and I want that if only one insert fails no records are created. Does the system require everything to be rolled back or should I apply a change?

Comment: You don't need to make any changes.